# macOS: Are nested disk images ok?

Tags: finder, disk-utility

I am using nested disk images to secure some of my files.

But I am getting read/write errors on a disk image that is inside another disk image.

Around 95% of the files are OK, but occasionally I cannot read or write a file any more but it is listed in Finder with the correct size.

This is what happens when I try to copy the file outside of the Disk Image (`can't complete the operation because some data in $x can't be read or written, Error code -36`):
[image]

This is what happens when I run Disk Utility first aid:

[image]